# How can i configure lampp for c++ web development

Tags: c++, web, cgi, lampp

I have this project with some time complexity issues and some complex algorithms and using c++ would be a great help in my project.
Thank You.

Comment: What are you tried so far at this time ? Please post code.

Comment: i am builing a time table generator for my college, have to data strucures in mind and i want to execute them with c++

Answer (score 1):

LAMP is originally an acronym for **L**inux **A**pache **M**YSQL **P**HP, it's not designed to work with c++ by design.

You can still use Apache with a C++ server connected to a database but I'd recommend using a c++ web development framework instead of doing all the work by yourself.

Some know and used frameworks :

- [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt)
- [CppCMS](http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/main)
- [TreeFrog Framework](http://www.treefrogframework.org/)

If you still want to use Apache and a database without any framework, those links might be useful :

- [How to connect mySQL database using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424828/how-to-connect-mysql-database-using-c)
- [How to use C++ for apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912761/how-to-use-c-for-apache-server)
- [MySQL connector for C++](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/)